# Fetch Instagram post's caption (to filter hashtag) using JS on WebApp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, instagram-api

I want to be able to fetch the caption of a Post or Reel from Instagram.

For example, I want to be able to do something like:

```
...
const [caption, setCaption] = useState<string>('');

axios.get('https://www.instagram.com/reel/Ch7i5hIJ--T/').then((res) => setCaption(res.data));
```

I know that they used to open `?__a=1` but it was deprecated back in 2019.